# Suggest parametric equations for a given curve

Tags: reference-request, parametric, plane-curves

Can anyone suggest a pair of parametric equations involving trigonometric functions that could give a curve with the following shape?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do without trigonometric functions by taking a cubic Bezier curve like this one (see fig. below):

$$\binom{x}{y}=s^3\binom{x_A}{y_A}+3s^2t\binom{x_B}{y_B}+3st^2\binom{x_C}{y_C}+t^3\binom{x_D}{y_D}$$

$$ \text{with} \ s:=1-t \ \text{and ''guiding'' points :} \ A(0,0), \ B(9,-1), \ C(5,4), \ D(4,-3), \ $$

giving:

$$\begin{cases}x=3*9*(t-2t^2+t^3)+3*5*(t^2-t^3)+4*t^3\\
y=3*(-1)*(t-2t^2+t^3)+3*4*(t^2-t^3)+(-3)*t^3\end{cases}$$

(I don't expand and reduce these expressions because small adjustments are easier to do under this form).

[image]

Comment: I'm aware of the concept. Is there any other way of producing a similar curve with simple trigonometric functions?

Comment: The solution provided by @Yves Daoust (associated with a -45° rotation and a convenient clipping) looked me satisfying...

Comment: Jean Marie, an automatic flag was raised by the system (two identical answers). I deleted the unvoted copy. If I missed something, and there are actually two different answers, please @-ping me (or raise a flag when any diamond moderator will take a look).

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen My bad. I didn't notice. It has happened me in the past, but I had always noticed it later on... Should I erase all the content of this copy, or we stay like this ?

Comment: It seems to me that this copy is the more comprehensive one (and the only one that collected any votes). I think leaving this as it is is the best course of action. No real harm done.

Answer (score 2):

The "right-angle-like" curve reminds of the astroid, which is a particular case of the hypocycloid, a rolling curve (with four cusps).

To obtain the small loop, you keep the rolling but take the current point a little outside the rolling circle, and this yields an hypotrochoid.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Astroid.html

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypocycloid.html

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypotrochoid.html

[image]

Remains to rotate it by 45°, which is elementary.

Comment: The curve I have drawn is one from an example sheet, whose equation I cannot remember, but it wasn't symmetric about y = x.

Comment: @wrb98: stretch it or clip it.

Comment: It's as it appears in the sketch I've attached. The left hand tail goes below the x-axis slightly and the loop is above the x-axis and in the first quadrant

Answer (score 2):

```
R = 5; r = 4; d = 2;
ParametricPlot[{(R - r) Cos[t] + d Cos[(R/r - 1) t], (R - r) Sin[t] - 
   d Sin[(R/r - 1) t]}, {t, 0, 25}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

You can play with constants ( radii of big circle $R$, small circle $r$, crank length $d$) producing a variety of *Hypo-Cycloids*. Loop size can be varied and start angle can be also added and set inside the sin/cos trig arguments.

[image: Hypocycloids]

Comment: Not very different from the solution by Yves Daoust.

Comment: Yep, except that OP is now free to  choose  $R,r,d$ constants in the parameterization  and see how  formation of multiple loops and their relative  size is influenced.

Comment: You are right. Like individuals, curves ask for more degree of freedom...

Comment: :) Vous avez raison !